# how can we modify cron expression to not to run on specific date, say 28th Dec and 3rd February

Tags: cron

- I already have a cron expression as : " 35 6 * * 2-6 ", which states the
  job will run every morning 6:35 from tuesday to saturday.
- I want to exclude 28th Dec and 3rd Feb from this expression.
- We are evaluating this cron expression in java code.
- These expressions are for jobs written in java.
- There is a parent job A.
- It has two child jobs A1 and A2.
- For job A to run, both A1 and A2 should be successful.
- I need to configure this exceptional date parameter for A1 and A2 with 
  existing cron condition.
- Both A1 and A2 should not run on 28th Dec and 3rd Feb.
- Can anyone please assist.

Comment: Anyone please...

Answer (score 0):

You could split your cronjob into three:

```
35 6 *          1,3-11 2-6 A1.sh && A2.sh
35 6 1-2,4-28   2      2-6 A1.sh && A2.sh
35 6 1-27,29-31 12     2-6 A1.sh && A2.sh
```

Where `A1.sh` and `A2.sh` are shell script that would execute your child jobs `A1` and `A2`. Make sure the shell scripts have the right permission.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing is there is a parent job A. It has two child jobs A1 and A2. This above condition needs to be configured for A1 and A2. Lets say now we will have A1_1, A1_2, A1_3 jobs as well. If any one of them fails, the parent job will not run. E.g. For Febrauary month, first job will fail, and therefore the parent will not run.

Comment: well, I would suggest in that case to edit your question and explain your case further.

Comment: The cron expressions I provided above still correct for your use case. I don't know how you execute your jobs exactly! I edited according to what I understood.